# How to get list widgetID in samsung smart tv?

Tags: widget, samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

need to get list widgetID in samsung smart tv.
How?
( getSearchWidgetListPath returned blank  file://localhost/mtd_down/common/WidgetMgr/searchWidgetList.xml )
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this programm:

it's a .exe file. All you have to do is put the packaged.zip files in the programm widget folder.

http://forum.samygo.tv/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=6560

then put the ip ypou specified in the tv and upload it.